# How to programmatically decline a cellular call on iPhone without Jailbreak

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I want to programatically decline a native/cellular call (no VoIP) on an iPhone. Is it possible? My internet research tells me no, still I am curious how e.g. third-party wearables can offer that.

Does anyone have further information?

Comment: No sure it's possible, you can read this as information [CallKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/callkit).

Comment: afaik it only (fully) handles VoIP Calls

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not currently possible with iOS.

However, you *can* display text when a users phone rings. Check out [CallKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/callkit) for more info.